# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{(4x^2-9)^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve the integral $$\int \frac{dx}{(4x^2-9)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: When you see a difference of squares, it suggests a trigonometric substitution.  What is that substitution, and what happens when you apply it here?

Comment: Tank you @GEdgar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the the denominator to $$\left(4x^2-9 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} = 8 \left( x^2-\frac{9}{4} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}.$$ Then apply the secant substitution, $$x=\frac{3}{2}\sec \theta,$$ and continue in the usual manner.

Comment: $$\int \frac{dx}{(4x^2-9)^{3/2}}=\int \frac{dx}{4^{3/2}\cdot{(x^2-\frac{9}{4})^{3/2}}}=\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt(x^2-\frac{9}{4})^3}$$
$$$$
And now??

Comment: Now find $dx$ (by differentiating your secant substitution), $x^2$ and then $x^2-\frac{9}{4}$. Do the total substitution, and wrangle it out. Show me more! It works like the last one you posted where I cranked the whole thing out for you. You are just doing a different substitution and so your integration and back substitution will be over something different.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt(x^2-\frac{9}{4})^3}$$
doing so $x=\frac{3}{2}\sec\theta$ then $dx=\frac{3}{2}\sec\theta\cdot\tan\theta$
$$\frac{1}{8}\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt(x^2-\frac{9}{4})^3}=\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{\frac{3}{2}\sec\theta \cdot \tan\theta\cdot d\theta}{\sqrt((\frac{3}{2}\sec\theta)^2-\frac{9}{4})^3}=\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot\tan\theta\cdot d\theta}{\sqrt(\frac{9}{4}\sec^2 \theta-\frac{9}{4})^3}$$

Comment: Looking good. Now $\left(\frac{9}{4} \sec^2 \theta -\frac{9}{4} \right)=\frac{9}{4}\tan^2 \theta$. Keep going.

Comment: More and hub????

Comment: $$\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot\tan\theta\cdot d\theta}{\sqrt(\frac{9}{4}\sec^2 \theta-\frac{9}{4})^3}=\frac{3}{16}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot\tan\theta\cdot d\theta}{\sqrt(\frac{9}{4}(\sec^2 \theta-1))^3}=\frac{3}{16}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot\tan\theta\cdot d\theta}{\sqrt(\frac{9}{4}\tan^2\theta)^3}=\frac{3}{16}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot\tan\theta\cdot d\theta}{\sqrt(\frac{729}{64}\tan^6\theta)}?$$

Comment: On that last step, the denominator will be $\frac{27}{8}\tan^3 \theta$. Notice that is $\left( \frac{9}{4} \tan^2 \theta \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: But let just by being in the root, am I wrong?

Comment: $$\frac{3}{16}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot\tan\theta \cdot d\theta}{\sqrt(\frac{729}{64}\tan^6\theta)}=\frac{3}{16}\int\frac{\sec\theta \cdot \tan\theta \cdot d\theta}{\frac{27}{8}\tan^3\theta}=\frac{1}{18}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot d\theta}{\tan^2\theta}$$

Comment: I'm having trouble passing the last equality! : (

Comment: You have to integrate that. Express it in terms of sines and cosines maybe? You will get $-\csc \theta +c$. Show your work. You might even post a self answer here once you are finished.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{18}\int\frac{\sec\theta\cdot d\theta}{\tan^2\theta}=\frac{1}{18}\int \frac{\frac{1}{\cos\theta}}{\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta}}d\theta=\frac{1}{18}\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} d \theta\\=\frac{1}{18}\int\cot \theta \csc\theta  d \theta =\fbox{$-\frac{1}{18}\csc\theta+C$}$$

Comment: Can not believe it!!
And now, as a step in terms of $x$?

Comment: I do not know how to do it not!

Comment: From your substitution it follows that $\sec \theta = \frac{2x}{3}$ ($2x$ on the hypoteneuse, and 3 adjacent to $\theta$). Draw that right triangle, then find the side opposite $\theta$ to be $\sqrt{4x^2-9}$ by Pythagorean theorem. Read off $\csc \theta$ from that construction and you are done.

Comment: CONSEGUI, ATÉ QUE ENFIM, MUITO OBRIGADO!!!!

Comment: Perhaps this would better if it were moved to chat.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F%284x%5E2%20-9%29%5E%283%2F2%29&x=-989&y=-7).

The answer is 
$$
-\frac{x}{9\sqrt{4x^2-9}} + c  $$ where $c$ is constant.

Comment: The question is HOW TO solve the integral, NOT what is the ANSWER to the integral

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{dx}{(4x^2-9)^3}$$
First, separate out $4^{\frac32}$
$$\int\frac{dx}{(4^{\frac{3}{2}})(x^2-\frac94)^3}$$
$$\frac{1}{18}\int\frac{dx}{(x^2-\frac94)^3}$$
Substitute in $x=\frac{3}{2}{\sec{x}}$ and calculate the derivative $dx=\frac{3}{2}\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}d{\theta}$
$$\frac{1}{18}\int\frac{\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}}{{\sqrt{{\frac{9}{4}\sec^2{\theta}-\frac94}}^3}}d{\theta}$$
Separate out constants and substitute $\sec^2{\theta}-1$ for $\tan^2{\theta}$
$$\frac{1}{18}\int\frac{\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}}{\tan^2{\theta}}d{\theta}$$
Rewrite in terms of $\cos{\theta}$ and $\sin{\theta}$
$$\frac{1}{18}\int\frac{\cos{\theta}}{\sin^2{\theta}}d{\theta}$$
Rewrite in terms of $\cot{\theta}\csc{\theta}$
$$\frac{1}{18}\int\cot{\theta}\csc{\theta}d{\theta}$$
Calculate the integral
$$\frac{-1}{18}\csc{\theta}+c$$
Resubstitute $x$ for $\theta$
$$x=\frac32\sec{\theta}$$
$$\sec{\theta}=\frac{2x}{3}$$
$$\cos{\theta}=\frac{3}{2x}$$
Use the Pythagorean Theorem
$$3^2+y^2=4x^2$$
From this, determine $\sin{\theta}$
$$\sin{\theta}=\frac{\sqrt{4x^2-9}}{2x}$$
Final Answer
$$\frac{-x}{9\sqrt{4x^2-9}}+c$$

Answer (score 0):

$x = \frac{3}{2}\cosh t$ should be the obvious substitution to solve it.

$$\int \frac{\frac{3}{2}\sinh t ~dt}{9^{3/2} \sinh^3 dt} = \frac{1}{18} \int\frac{dt}{\sinh^2 t} = \frac{1}{18} \coth t + \mathcal{C} $$

Thus

$$\int\frac{dx}{\left(4x^2 - 9\right)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{18} \coth\left(\cosh^{-1} \frac{2x}{3}\right) +\mathcal {C}$$